# Key grabbing under wayland (shortcuts won't work in virt-manager)

Tags: xorg, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, wayland

I use virt-manager on Ubuntu 17.10.1 (both host and guest). Key grabbing won't work. That is, I can't do control tab inside the guest machine for example.

I discovered that it has to do with Wayland:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1285770

I've followed the entire discussion, and at the end they say that this problem is fixed for applications built natively for wayland. I guess virt-manager isn't, because it doesn't work for me.

How to grab keys in virt-manager using wayland?

Comment: The fix came after 17.10 was released, so don't expect it until 18.04 (or later).

Comment: Having the same issue on 18.04. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: @christophetd don't think it's going to be solved soon. You can switch to xorg easely by logging off and then in the login screen clicking on the gear icon and choosing xorg.